# How do I save a physical file starting from a TJSONObject?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe4

How do I save a physical .json file to my C: \ drive starting from my JSONObject3 object?

```
procedure CreateJSON;
var
  JSONObject2, JSONObject3: TJSONObject;
  JSONValue1, JSONValue2: TJSONValue;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
  JSONString1, JSONString2: TJSONString;
  AText, BText: string;
  mStringStream:      TStringStream;
begin
  JSONObject2 := TJSONObject.Create;
  JSONObject3 := TJSONObject.Create;
  JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  try   
    AText := 'Name';
    BText := '"Charles"';
    JSONString2 := TJSONString.Create(AText);
    JSONValue2 :=  TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(BText);

    JSONObject2.AddPair(JSONString2, JSONValue2);   
    JSONArray.Add(JSONObject2);    
    JSONObject3.AddPair('People', JSONArray);

    mStringStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
    // m_StringStream.LoadFromStream(JSONObject3.ToString); <---ERROR
    mStringStream.SaveToFile('people.json');
  finally
    JSONObject3.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thank you, I am a beginner with the json topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TJSONObject` does not have any streaming support, but it does have several `To...()` output methods (`ToBytes()`, `ToJSON()` `ToString()`). The output of any of those methods can be written to a file, such as with `TFile.WriteAll...()` methods (`WriteAllBytes()`, `WriteAllText()`).

Try this instead:

```pascal
uses
  ...,
  Data.DBXJSON, // use System.JSON in XE6+
  System.IOUtils,
  System.SysUtils;

procedure CreateJSON;
var
  JSONObject, JSONObject2: TJSONObject;
  JSONValue: TJSONValue;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
  AText, BText: string;
begin
  JSONObject := TJSONObject.Create;
  try   
    AText := 'Name';
    BText := '"Charles"';

    JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(BText);
    if JSONValue <> nil then
    try
      JSONObject.AddPair(AText, JSONValue);
    except
      JSONValue.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    JSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    try
      JSONObject2 := TJSONObject.Create;
      try
        JSONArray.Add(JSONObject2);
      except
        JSONObject2.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      JSONObject.AddPair('People', JSONArray);
    except
      JSONArray.Free;
      raise;
    end;

    TFile.WriteAllText('people.json', JSONObject.ToJSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    JSONObject.Free;
  end;
end;
```